# Truncating a string from last till a character is encountered in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string with a path like so:

```
C:/myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile.doc
```

I need to truncate the string to become:

```
myfile.doc
```

Needless to say, I have a list of such paths with different lengths and different folder depths. What I need is something like trancating the rest of the string beginning from the last of the string till the first / is encountered.

How can I achieve this in PHP.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function for this.

```
echo basename("C:/myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile.doc");
```

Output:

```
myfile.doc
```

Note that this doesn't exactly do what you described, because for these inputs:

```
/etc/
.
```

it would return

```
etc
.
```

So an (untested) alternative could be:

```
$fullname = "C:/myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile.doc";
$parts = explode("/", $fullname);
$filename = $parts[count($parts)-1];
echo $filename;
```

Comment: If one assume, that there may be non-files in the list and its required, that everything is a file, one should use `is_file()`

Answer (score 3):

```
$path = 'C:/myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile.doc':
$filename = basename($path);
echo $filename; // "myfile.doc"
```

See [Manual "basename()"](http://php.net/basename). For more detailed information about a path see [pathinfo()](http://php.net/pathinfo)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want the filename segment, you can use `basename()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php